# Why large strides have poor spatial locality?

Tags: c, computer-science

I read 《Computer Systems: A Programmer's Perspective》.
The section of Locality in chapter 6.The book think Programs that hop around memory with large strides have poor spatial locality.

So, How to get this conclusion?
 thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Just think about the definition of spatial locality:

> Spatial locality
>   If a particular memory location is referenced at a particular time, then it is likely that nearby memory locations will be referenced in the near future. In this case it is common to attempt to guess the size and shape of the area around the current reference for which it is worthwhile to prepare faster access.

Therefore, if the locations you are accessing are not nearby, given that you are hoping around the memory in 'big strides', your program has poor spatial locality.

Comment: thank you. ok, striedes-1000 should be more faster than strieds-1. But striedes-2 whether will be faster than striedes-1?

Comment: That would depend on factors like page and cache size, I suppose.

Comment: thank you. I think the answer is: Because of spatial locality, we can expect that the cost of copying a block after a miss will be amortized by subsequent references to other objects within that block.